# Core Data Not Equal Predicate

Tags: ios, core-data

```
name <> myname
```

I feel a bit stupid asking this question, but I am using the predicate above in a subquery. I was expecting to see all rows where name was not equal to my name. However, rows that have a NULL value for name are not being returned. Is this correct behavior?

Comment: If you're playing with strings, `<>`  could be a bad solution. See at `LIKE`, `NOT`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is to be expected. See [Null Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW1) in the "Predicate Programming Guide":

> A comparison predicate does not match any value with null except null
>   (`nil`) or the `NSNull` null value (that is, (`$value == nil`) returns `YES`
>   if `$value` is `nil`).
>   ...
>   If you want to match null values, you must include a specific test in addition to other comparisons, ...

That means that *both* `"name = myname"` and `"name <> myname"` evaluate to NO if `name`
is NULL.

You can change your predicate to

```
name <> myname OR name = NULL
```

to cover both cases.